# Getting handshake error while creating profile in Local composer-playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

While creating a profile to connect to a hyperledger fabric instance, I get the following error.

```
0|composer | HLFConnection :login() > admin
0|composer | E0508 11:50:42.311834619 75 ssl_transport_security.c:611] Could not load any root certificate.
0|composer | E0508 11:50:42.311850655 75 ssl_transport_security.c:1348] Cannot load server root certificates.
0|composer | E0508 11:50:42.312139228 75 security_connector.c:837] Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.
0|composer | E0508 11:50:42.312149486 75 secure_channel_create.c:127] Failed to create secure subchannel for secure name.
```

When I check the loaded certificate in the playground logs, '\r\n' has been changed to '\\r\\n'

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with the certificate text box when you enter the PEM certificate as a single string.
There are a couple of ways to get around the problem for now. You either need to remove all the \r\n text from the text before putting into the cert field on the UI, or you can import your current connection profile which you use for connection via the command line.

Following is the link to issue in github.

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/893