# Root Certificate error when installing runtime

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying a multi-org tutorial from here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org and everything works well until step 11. I get the following error when running that step:

I found a similar issue posted earlier resolved: [Getting handshake error while creating profile in Local composer-playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855088/getting-handshake-error-while-creating-profile-in-local-composer-playground)

I also removed /r/n from the keys as some had suggested, but I still get the error

```
$ composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -n trade-network

⠹ Installing runtime for business network trade-network. This may take 
a minute...E0214 06:16:49.380034000 140735945052992 
ssl_transport_security.c:584] Could not load any root certificate.
E0214 06:16:49.380074000 140735945052992 ssl_transport_security.c:1297] 
Cannot load server root certificates.
E0214 06:16:49.380108000 140735945052992 security_connector.c:857]     
Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.
E0214 06:16:49.380118000 140735945052992 secure_channel_create.c:112]  
Failed to create secure subchannel for secure name 'localhost:7053'
E0214 06:16:49.380124000 140735945052992 secure_channel_create.c:143]  
Failed to create subchannel arguments during subchannel creation.
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your environment such as fabric version and composer version ?

Comment: `$composer --version v0.17.4` `fabric hlfv11`  I tried redoing everyhting from scratch and now I get `Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: `composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -n trade-network` fails but installing on second peer `PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1` works

Comment: Not sure what you mean by installing on second peer. When you install, you install onto all of the peers in the organisation. So when you use this card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 in the install command you are saying you want to install onto all the peers defined in the connection profile that belong to the organisation in the client section and use the associated certificate in the command to identify me.

Comment: Sorry, I meant installing on org1 fails but installing on org2 succeeds. That previous comment has typo, it should read "but installing for second org -  PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2 works"

Comment: It sounds like either something went wrong building the PeerAdmin card for org1, or perhaps it failed to import because there was an old card already there ? If you tore down everything and restarted then an old card from a previous run could report that error. Did you clear out file card store ?

Comment: Yes, ran `rm -rf ~/.composer` and used `composer card list` to make sure the old cards are gone before importing the new ones. Import worked without an error for both cards.

Comment: is it resolved ? Because I have the same bug in 0.19.0. Thx

Comment: I have the same error for V 0.19.1. Any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Your situation can be different but depending on whether or not you have volume persistence for containers and the method used for restarting the containers, certs may get updated. My issue got resolved when I updated the certificates I had already pasted in the `byfn-network.json` file in step 2.